# Getting hr line to go in between two other divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a `hr` tag to go in between two `div`s.

I have placed the `hr` tag under the first `div` and above the second. I set both `div`s and the `hr` tag to `display` as `inline` in hopes of this being a sequence and displaying one after the other. My problem is the `hr` tag starts at the very top and stops where the other `div`s are.

I have attached a fiddle to show what I am getting:

https://jsfiddle.net/31ytnun2/

```css
.contactpagelower {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.spancenter {
  text-align: center;
}
.contactpagecommunityContainer {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: inline;
}
.contactpagecommunity {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 37%;
  background-color: #12BDB8;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px;
}
.contactpagecommunity a:link {
  background-color: #12BDB8;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.contactpagecommunity a:visited {
  background-color: #12BDB8;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  outline: none;
}
.contactpagesellwithusContainer {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: inline;
}
.contactpagesellwithus {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 35%;
  background-color: #12BDB8;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px;
}
.contactpagesellwithus a:link {
  background-color: #12BDB8;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.contactpagesellwithus a:visited {
  background-color: #12BDB8;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  outline: none;
}
.hrafter {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="contactpagelower">
  <div class="spancenter"><span class="teallarge">Extras gfgfggsfgfgsfd</span>
  </div>

  <div class="contactpagecommunityContainer">
    <p class="subscribebodytext">We want to hear from you, let us know what we can do to make your experience better!</p>
    <button onClick="#" class="contactpagecommunity"><a href="community.php">Visit our community</a>
    </button>
  </div>
  <hr class="hrafter" width="1" size="500">
  <div class="contactpagesellwithusContainer">
    <p class="subscribebodytext">Have you ever wanted to sell a product? We may be able to help.</p>
    <button onClick="#" class="contactpagesellwithus"><a href="sellwithus.php">Sell with us</a>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried separating my two `div`s from each other by changing the `width`s hoping to get a gap in the middle. Like this:

```
.contactpagecommunityContainer {
    float: left;
    width: 49%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: inline;
}
.contactpagesellwithusContainer {
    float: right;
    width: 49%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: inline;
}
```

I also tried setting the `hr` to be `inline-block`, but that just pushed the second `div` (`.contactpagesellwithusContainer`) below where the `hr` tag stops.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `float: left` to `<hr/>` element and make second div 49% in width:

https://jsfiddle.net/31ytnun2/8/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/31ytnun2/4/)

```
.contactpagecommunityContainer {
    float: left;
    width: 49%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: inline;
}
.contactpagesellwithusContainer {
      float: right;
  width: 49%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: inline;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that made the affect. The only thing is my two divs are unequal size in height and I want the line to go past both by just a little bit.

Comment: you can create a div in between this two div and give css:border-left and adjust height accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Although `hr` denotes a thematic break, it is also shorthand for 'horizontal rule' so its arguable whether semantically it should be used vertically in the absence of an equivalent `vr` however, it is likely the closest element available.

Given your markup and what you're trying to achieve, you may be best placed with a CSS table, the advantage being that by replacing the `hr` with a cell border, it will scale with the content as appropriate.

```css
.contactpagelower {
    margin-top: 40px;
    display:table
}
.spancenter {
    text-align: center;
}
.contactpagecommunityContainer {
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: table-cell;
    padding:20px;
    width:50%;
}
.contactpagecommunity {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 37%;
    background-color: #12BDB8;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 15px;
}
.contactpagecommunity a:link {
    background-color: #12BDB8;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.contactpagecommunity a:visited {
    background-color: #12BDB8;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    outline: none;
}
.contactpagesellwithusContainer {
    display:table-cell;
    width:50%;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-left:1px solid;
}
.contactpagesellwithus {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 35%;
    background-color: #12BDB8;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 15px;
}
.contactpagesellwithus a:link {
    background-color: #12BDB8;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.contactpagesellwithus a:visited {
    background-color: #12BDB8;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="spancenter"> <span class="teallarge">Extras gfgfggsfgfgsfd</span>

</div>
<div class="contactpagelower">
    <div class="contactpagecommunityContainer">
        <p class="subscribebodytext">We want to hear from you, let us know what we can do to make your experience better!</p>
        <button onClick="#" class="contactpagecommunity"><a href="community.php">Visit our community</a>

        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="contactpagesellwithusContainer">
        <p class="subscribebodytext">Have you ever wanted to sell a product? We may be able to help.</p>
        <button onClick="#" class="contactpagesellwithus"><a href="sellwithus.php">Sell with us</a>

        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```